# How do you create an invisible div to trigger an event on dragEnter?

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, drag-and-drop

I have a div which serves as an area that triggers ondragEnter event to open up a pane at the bottom of the screen.  When I drag an HTML5 draggable object into this dnd-container, it will open the bottom pane.  The problem is, the draggable elements that are in the area of the dnd-container are not able to be dragged, which would trigger the ondragEnter event (since ondragStart event happens already inside the dnd-container).  I have to be outside of the dnd-container in order to drag the element successfully into the dnd-container which opens the bottom pane that displays the drop zone.
Any thoughts?  Perhaps I'm going about this the wrong way.

Code Snippets:

application.html

```
<div id="card-container"></div> <!--contains some objects that are draggable="true"-->
<div id="dnd-container"></div>
<div id="bp-container"></div>
```

layout.js

```
define(...{
    var AppLayout = Marionette.Layout.extend({
       template : tmpl,
       events : {
         'dragenter #dnd-container' : 'toggleBot',
       },
       toggleQB : function(){
          x.publish('toggleQB'); //just opens and closes the bottom pane
       },
   });
 return AppLayout;
});
```

styles.css

```
#dnd-container {
    position: fixed;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 28px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 70%;
    z-index: -1;
}

#bp-container {
    width : 100%;
    height: 275px;
    margin-left:auto;
    background-color: 000000;
    margin-right:auto;
   -moz-border-radius: 0px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px;
    border-radius: 7px 7px 0px 0px; 
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Show what code you have thus far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you get rid of the dnd-container, and just show the drop-zone pane at the bottom on the `dragstart` event, and hide it on the `dragend` event.

The `dragend` event will trigger if you drop it in the pane, somewhere it can't be dropped, or even if you hit the escape key while dragging.

Then in your drop-zone pane, handle the `drop` event.

Comment: True, I was thinking of doing this as an alternative.  I guess it's just as good, trying to think with my UX cap on.

Comment: IMO it is better UX this way as well. Even if the user drags outside the browser, you will see the drop-zone pane visible, so the user will have no confusion of where to drop :)